# Configuring VPN on a Samsung devices

Tags: vpn

I'm traveling in Iran and I would like to update my position on a website that uses Google Maps. The problem is that on my both Samsung Android devices I can't see the maps (the web site is not filtered and I can see everything but the map which is the main part of the application).

I think that Google Maps is filtered although in some internet cafe I can use maps.google.com but I still can't see the map on my application (and other international web sites that use Google Maps).
Is there any way to configure a VPN network on my Android devices (a smartphone and a tablet).

I don't know how it works and I can't access almost any tutorial (filtered)
. Thanks for any kind of help.
Last thing most of the time I use the wifi network in the rare hotel that have one.

Comment: What you're really asking for is **how to circumvent state sanctioned internet filtering**. VPN is a solution, but there are others too. Give TOR a try, here's an app on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.torproject.android). If you have any SSH access to a home box, this might also work (using ssh with dynamic forwards, *but* you need a running box with an ssh-server installed at home. Probably the safest/easiest/cheapest way for the next time).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Exactly I'm trying to circumvent internet filtering here in Iran. The maps on my routefollower journey do not show up. Unfortunately I don't have access to home box. How the TOR works? As you can imagine I'm not an expert. Thanks

Comment: I tryed with TOR but I cannot download as the other apps and their web site is filtered. I thought that maybe the app is not downloadable forthe same reason

Comment: You can't access Google play at all? Wow. Try F-Droid's [Orbot](http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=tor&fdid=org.torproject.android&fdpage=4) and [Orweb2](http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=tor&fdid=info.guardianproject.browser&fdpage=4)

Comment: If the linked downloads dont work copy paste them and change https to http, and retry.

Answer (score 1):

Some VPN providers, such as HMA, have instructions specific to Android devices, so its best to check with your VPN provider via their support page, as you're going to need their server and other info. All android devices support PPTP VPN, and there are some VPN's you can use for free such as Hideman which you can find in Google Play.

Here is a tutorial on basic configuration
http://www.vpntraffic.com/index.php?action=content&cont_id=26

Comment: Hi Mike thank you for your reply as I expected the link that you posted is filtered. Basically do I need to download an application? I thought I could set a vpn network by setting the parameters in "Settings"